# appendchild a React Component message

Tags: reactjs, appendchild

How add a React.js Component as a function using `appendChild` like the following:

```
const message = (reactComponent) => {
  document.body.appendChild(reactComponent);
}

const MyReactComponent = () => (<span>Welcome back </span>);

message(<MyReactComponent />);  // Send a message to the user
```

Comment: You don't. You render it using [`ReactDOM.render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render). You can still append the target element before you call the react render method though (if that's what you mean)

Comment: Can you let us know the use case you are targeting?

Comment: The point is that I want to be able to add the component outside of any component. For example, use this function on a button click ex: `<button onClick={ () => addToDom()>Add component to the dom</button>` and that I can use inside a redux function too.

Comment: I'm looking for a function that will send a message. Example: `message("You're now logged in!");`

Comment: I am looking for something that will have the same behavior as the and design message function (https://ant.design/components/message/).

Comment: As stated in my answer, the addition or subtraction of items to the DOM should be handled with state, and you should let react handle the actual dom modification. So your onClick event should fire, set the relevant state, and let react handle the dom modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

First I create the `message` function using the `rc-notification` package and put it in a separate folder named `message.js`:

```js
import Notification from "rc-notification";
import "rc-notification/assets/index.css";

let notification = null;
Notification.newInstance({}, (n) => notification = n);


function message(content) {
    notification.notice({ content });
}

export default message;
```

Then, I can import this function and use it to send a message to the user like the following:

```js
import React from "react";
import message from "./PATH_TO_MESSAGE_FUNC";

const App = () => {
  const MyReactComponent = () => <span>Welcome back </span>;
  successMessage(<MyReactComponent />);  // trigger on page load in this case
  
  return (
    <div>My app</div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't. You'd have to use an html element for that. Rather, you could use a ternary syntax to either show or hide an element in the render method:

```
render()
  return (
     {
        this.state.someState?<div>something</div>:<div>something else</div>
     }
  )
```

You can use the `onClick` event to trigger a method that sets your state as needed.

You could use props or state. The idea is to set the prop or state as needed to append, hide, or switch which element you'd like to be visible.